# for loop not working: "not a statement"

Tags: java, for-loop, error-handling

```
if(fightAnswer == true) {
        System.out.println("Let's do this.\n");

        for(dude.speed >= mob1.speed; mob1.defense > 0;
            mob1.defense = mob1.defense - dude.strength) {

            Scanner inFight = new Scanner(System.in);
            mob1.showAttributes();
            System.out.println("Continue fighting? (y/n)");
            fightChoice = inFight.hasNext();
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
}
```

I am unable to compile that for loop. I have been looking around for some solution, but I don't seem to quite understand the mistake(s) here.
Please advise!!
Many thanks to all in advance.

Comment: `for(initialization; iterationCondition; incrementation)` take a look at your code and see if it matches this formula.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `dude.speed >= mob1.speed`?  It doesn't seem to be an initialisation statement for your loop.  Did you mean it to be part of an `if` condition somewhere?

Comment: I meant it to be the initialisation, but I guess you are right. I have replaced the foor loop with the following:
`for(; mob1.defense > 0; mob1.defense = mob1.defense - dude.strength) { }`
Somehow this seems to have worked, but I don't know where to place the speed statement.

Comment: If there's no specific initialisation required, you may be better off using a `while` loop.

Comment: The `while` worked just fine. Thank you all so much for your quick and really helpful responses.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try

```
for (;;(dude.speed>=mob1.speed||mob1.defense>=0) {
...
```

that should make the loop run as long as `dude.speed` is greater than `mob1.speed` OR if `mob1.defense` is greather than 0... is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: Thank you so much for all your quick answers.
Basically, I wanted to condition to be that if dude.speed > mob1.speed AND mob1.defense > 0, then mob1.defense = mob1.defense - dude.strength.
Finally, the block code would complete the little for loop.